# MySql select rows that have multiple records with date differance

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL table that stores user operations , in other words it's like operations log that may contains duplicate rows with same user_id.table structured as follow:

```
id  operation_name     role    operation_type   user_id   ... creation_date
 1   delivery          driver    1               2901         2018-05-23 06:06:22
 2   ride              driver    2               1197         2018-02-23 05:54:22
 1   delivery          driver    1               2901         2018-08-23 18:06:29
```

i want to select the rows with same user id and creation date in between a period of time not duplicate.
for example i want to select all the users ids that has did more than n operations between x period of time .

I tried the following query but its not working :

```
 SELECT user_id  FROM operations_log where 
        creation_date between creation_date and DATE_ADD(creation_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) group by 
   user_id;
```

Comment: Please give us an example of desired output.

Comment: what dates will you select thiswhat you doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the HAVING clause.

```
    SELECT user_id  FROM operations_log where 
        creation_date between creation_date and DATE_ADD(creation_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) group by 
   user_id HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

`Group By` requires `Having` to utilize the aggregate function you'd need, which is `count`

Comment: The `creation_date` criteria should be in `WHERE`, not `HAVING`. Otherwise you're just checking an arbitrary row from the group.

Comment: Ah I see, I undid an edit I made thinking it had to be in the having.  I think when you have aggregate functions, you'd have to switch things around anyways.

Comment: You don't need `DISTINCT` since grouping by `user_id` forces it to be distinct.